# It's possible to build 2 apk on android one with high resolution graphics

Tags: android, apk, assets

I am a Android developer with some games published on the GooglePlay. Actually i have 2 apk files for OS version (one with mutitouch support 2.0+ and the other without mutitouch support 1.5+) using the multiapk support existing on GooglePlay.

The 2 apk's has high resolution assets for HD devices but in some old phones causes Memory problems loading and re-scalign hd images.

To solve this problem i want to build my apk with low res assets (more compatibility, better memory allocation) and build another apk with only the high resolution assets.

APK 1: the game (with low res graphics)
APK 2: high resolution assets for the game

The user donwloads the game and, when it's started, the game check the screen resolution and asks the user if wants to download and install high resolution assets.

I don't want to use the multiple apk because it's too dificult to mantain (4 apk's). It's any solution i can use to do that?

Something like expansion pack but in the internal memory (structure of the app)

Thanks.
Ricard.

Answer (score 0):

1. What you can do to limit work overload is to have two [Android Libraries](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject), oner with small graphics and one with HD, and make your application use one or the other lib at compilation time. Of course you'll need to make sure the drawable names and layouts and ids are exactly the same. This creates more apk but it can be done in no time. Note that you could limit this to 2 APK, by detecting programatically the OS version :

   ```
   if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
       // use single touch
   } else {
       // use multi touch
   }
   ```
2. You can also use your idea of a HD Pack, downloaded from the market with jsut your drawables in them. You can access resources from your second app using the following code :

   ```
   Resources res = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication("com.example.foo")
   ```

   Then you would need to know exactly the correct drawable ids to load the correct one or just use reflection.
3. Another option would be to store an archive with all your drawable, download them from your own server into the application sandbox and read them from the disk instead of from the resources.

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer but isn't what i search.

Comment: I edited my answer for clarity. Isn't the point 2 what you want ?

Comment: Sorry with my crazy fingers. I like your solution (point 2). I understand that: i can compile the game with lowres assets and upload another package with the hd assets and from the game, obtain the resources of the hd package.
I don't understant your first point. How one single apk with android target < 2.0 can accept multitouch events? (only OS 2.0+ can be used with multitouch events). Thankyou again.

Comment: For my first solution, you build two "HandleTouch" classes to handle any touch input, the first one uses the single touch for Android 1.5+, the second one uses multitouch for 2.0+. In your code, you can detect if the current OS Version, using the code I provide, and then use one or the other class accodringly. This mean that all users have the same app, and the app behaves differently on all devices.